# PCF: How to find the list of all the spaces where you have Developer privileges

Tags: cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

If you are not an admin in Pivotal Cloud Foundry, how will you find or list all the orgs/spaces where you have developer privileges? Is there a command or menu to get that, instead of going into each space and verifying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a script that will dump the org & space names of which the currently logged in user is a part.

A quick explanation. It will call the `/v2/spaces` api, which already filters to only show spaces of which the currently logged in user can see (if you run with a user that has admin access, it will list all orgs and spaces). We then iterate over the results & take the space's `organization_url` field and `cf curl` that to get the organization name (there's a hashmap to cache results).

This script requires Bash 4+ for the hashmap support. If you don't have that, you can remove that part and it will just be a little slower. It also [requires `jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), and of course the cf cli.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# List all spaces available to the current user
#
set -e

function load_all_pages {
    URL="$1"
    DATA=""
    until [ "$URL" == "null" ]; do
        RESP=$(cf curl "$URL")
        DATA+=$(echo "$RESP" | jq .resources)
        URL=$(echo "$RESP" | jq -r .next_url)
    done
    # dump the data
    echo "$DATA" | jq .[] | jq -s
}

function load_all_spaces {
    load_all_pages "/v2/spaces"
}

function main {
    declare -A ORGS  # cache org name lookups

    # load all the spaces & properly paginate
    SPACES=$(load_all_spaces)

    # filter out the name & org_url
    SPACES_DATA=$(echo "$SPACES" | jq -rc '.[].entity | {"name": .name, "org_url": .organization_url}')

    printf "Org\tSpace\n"
    for SPACE_JSON in $SPACES_DATA; do
        SPACE_NAME=$(echo "$SPACE_JSON" | jq -r '.name')
        # take the org_url and look up the org name, cache responses for speed
        ORG_URL=$(echo "$SPACE_JSON" | jq -r '.org_url')
        ORG_NAME="${ORGS[$ORG_URL]}"
        if [ "$ORG_NAME" == "" ]; then
            ORG_NAME=$(cf curl "$ORG_URL" | jq -r '.entity.name')
            ORGS[$ORG_URL]="$ORG_NAME"
        fi
        printf "$ORG_NAME\t$SPACE_NAME\n"
    done
}

main "$@"
```